# Simplest way read/write a small JSON file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JavaScript array of objects for an arcade-style leader board in my video game. So, the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {"initials" : "JOE", "score": 20250},
    {"initials" : "ACE", "score": 10010},
    {"initials" : "YUP", "score": 5500}
]
```

At the end of the game, I want to read the current leader board array from file on the server into JS and, if the player made the leaderboard, modify the array and write it back to leader board file.

Conceptually simple, but I spent the better part of the day reading up on PHP, AJAX, jQuery, and since I'm new to these technologies, my heads spinning a bit, mostly because the examples I'm finding are for much more complex situations than mine.

What's the simplest way to read a JSON array from file into JavaScript and then write it back again if the JSON array is the only thing in the file? My hosting service is running PHP 5.5.

EDIT:
After incorporating some feedback and reading up some more, below's what I came up, which works.

```
// read leader board
function readLeaderboard() {
    var scores = [];
    // load json without caching
    var nonCacheableURL = 'js/leaderboard.json?nocache=' + (new   
        Date()).getTime();
    $.getJSON(nonCacheableURL, function(json) {
        for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            scores[i] = json[i];
        }
    });
    return scores;
}

// save leader board
function saveLeaderboard(leaderboard) {
    $.post('js/postLeaderboard.php', {json : JSON.stringify(leaderboard)},
        function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){}
    );
}
```

Which calls postLeaderboard.php:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("leaderboard.json",  $_POST['json']);
?>
```

Comment: Just load the JSON using `file_get_contents()` or using file handlers and decode it using `json_decode` and after editing the decoded JSON `json_encode()` it again and put it in the file using `file_put_contents()` or file handlers.

Comment: suggestion: don't modify the array on the client-side and then send it back but let the client-side script only report the score and let the server-side script decide what to do (and how) with that data.

Comment: You need a server that has access to that file that you can create a request on that server that will update the file locally on the server.  This requires server-side changes.  Likely cannot be done only via client.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can follow these lines:

to read JSON and get an Assoc Array from it:

```
$scores = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('scores.json'));
```

to write array into JSON file:

```
file_put_contents('scores.json', json_encode($scores));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I know in PHP is to do something like this:

```
// Get the Data
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");
// Decode the json in it and store it,
$decoded = json_decode($data);
// Manipulate the $decoded here...


// JSON encode the object - $decoded and store it in a variable
$modified = json_encode($decode);

// put it back in the file
/* if you want to append the data, uncomment this-
$prev = true;
*/
if(isset($prev) && $prev = true)
{
    file_put_contents("data.json", $prev . $modified);
}
else{
    file_put_contents("data.json", $modified);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I had tried implementing something simpler but struggled with getting it into JS. The above is pure PHP. How do I get the JSON into JS?

Comment: I would use `$.get` ajax function and fetch that JSON and eval it and put it in a variable and access various data. :-). Like: 
`var json;
$.get("data.json", function(data){json = data;});
var obj = eval(json);
//manipulate or fetch values from obj...`